# Securing API key in HTTP request

Tags: ios, security, ssl, translate, api-key

After a day of searching for SSL and HTTPS, I'm completely confused on how to do something very simple. I have a small app that has no kind of user authentication. All users see a simple app.

I am trying to use Google translate API for this. I have a translate API key, but I'm completely oblivious to how to protect it. I want to call Google translate directly from my iOS app, and according to the api docs (https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest), the apiKey is provided as a request parameter 'key'. The API docs also say that Google translate supports SSL, but obviously I'm not doing any kind of SSL checks on my ios app to confirm the identity. My question is, how do i stop a MITM attack that can obtain my translate API key and abuse it? I tried using Charles and I am clearly able to see the key being passed through.

Every resource I've read on the Internet says they use SSL, and all is good. But there's no examples on how to use SSL in iOS apps using popular services like Google.

Any ideas on how I can make this simple GET request and prevent my key from being stolen?

**EDIT:**

SSL Pinning is an overkill for this. I'm not thinking about using SSL, but I have no idea how that works with iOS, and an entity like Google (as per discussion with @pvg below).

Comment: You can try implementing your own SSL pinning but it's complete overkill for your translate API key. It's not valuable enough for anyone to steal nor is it difficult to replace.

Comment: Exactly, implementing SSL pinning is a complete overkill. I'll have to set up my own server, buy my own SSL certificate, etc. The reason my translate API key is valuable is because otherwise someone could easily get it and abuse it with the sole intention of costing me money.

Comment: No you don't need your own server and certificate, but again, nobody is going to steal your API key and if they did, chances are you will not be liable for the usage. You can take this up with Google if you are super paranoid but at that point it's not really a programming question. It's not much of a programming question as it is.

Comment: How would I not need my own server and certificate if i choose to implement SSL pinning? I'm just using an API, so I don't have access to Google's certificate that I can store in my bundle. Again, still learning about SSL, so excuse any of my misunderstandings about SSL pinning

Comment: You know the certs because they are public. You can use a library like this https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit (or at least, use it as a starting point). It's also a good way to silently break your app in the future, if you get it wrong. I'd recommend you just use SSL as is.

Comment: Well that brings me to my most frustrated question of the day: how do you use SSL on iOS. I know there's delegate methods that need to be implemented to check the server's certificate, but let's go with my example of Google Translate. What validation would I be doing in those methods? What would the flow look like? There's so many examples for the more complicated SSL requests, but nothing for something simple. What request will I have to make so that my ios client does the certificate validation and then uses the private key in the certificate to encrypt my translate api key?

Comment: You'll have to write some code and ask those questions (hopefully with an an [MCVE]) separately and specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use HTTPS because you don't want people to have your API key. Have you tohught about where that API key would be stored, if your app connects directly to Google Translate? :)

You will have to distribute your API key to Google Translate with your app. Pretty much everybody will have it that way. This may or may not be a problem, I think Google API keys are usually in Javascript sent to browser clients anyway, so they are not that big of a secret. The only way to protect it from users is to run your own server that translates your app queries into Google Translate queries using your API key stored on your server.

(Maybe this is obvious, but note that HTTPS is a transport protocol, it protects data in motion, ie. when it is sent over the network, but not data at rest, ie. when it's in your app on a mobile phone.)

As for how to make sure nobody is impersonating Google's servers, and whether you need certificate pinning. Certificates are your guarantee that in most scenarios, this is not possible. Pretty much any standard method you choose to communicate with a https webserver, your underlying framework and/or operating system will validate the server certificate and make sure there is no impersonation. That's what certificates are for. Certificate pinning is for mitigating the threat of something like a rogue trusted root certificate being installed on the client. Like for example in corporate networks, it's often the case that a company CA root certificate is installed as trusted root on managed clients, and from then on, the company proxy can peek into client SSL traffic too by forging server keys and certificates. This is only possible, because the company root cert is preinstalled, it is not possible for an attacker. A similar threat is when an attacker manages to install his certificate on a client as a trusted root, but that is not very common anymore. You may want protection against it depending on your threat model, but in most cases using standard web clients to talk to an https API is enough validation of the server, you can be sure that when you download something from https://google.com, that actually comes from google.com.

Comment: Thanks for the response Gabor. I realized after searching a bit that yes, my API key would be stored in the app bundle itself, and anyone can use a string utility to get the key that way. Then I can scratch this method I guess. I was trying to avoid needed to set up my own server that simply sends a translate request to Google, all just to safeguard an API key.